# pass php value to python as sys.argv

Tags: python, php, html

I wanna pass a checkbox value into a python script and add to a list.

My php file:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

Which buildings do you want access to?<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Acorn" />Acorn Building<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Brown" />Brown Hall<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Carnegie" />Carnegie Complex<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Drake" />Drake Commons<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="Elliot" />Elliot House

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>

<?php
  $aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
  } 
  else 
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");      
    }
    echo $output;
  }
?>
```

My Python Script:

```
import sys

params = []

if ("Acorn" in str(sys.argv)):
    params += ["Acorn Building"]

if ("Brown" in str(sys.argv)):
    params += ["Brown Hall"]
    
if ("Carnegie" in str(sys.argv)):
    params += ["Carnegie Complex"]

if ("Drake" in str(sys.argv)):
    params += ["Drake Common"]

if ("Elliot" in str(sys.argv)):
    params += ["Elliot House"]

print (params)
```

so if i checked the "Acorn Buildung" and "Drake Common" that go through the if statement in python and
(the "print (params)" is for check the params's string)

The problem is the python doesn't recognise the sys.argv() and doesn't go through the if statement what should i Change?

Comment: for appending parameters into the list `+=` not best practice. instead use `append` function. .e.g. `params.append("Acorn Building")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cast `sys.argv` to a string.

If the script was called like `python3 test.py Elliot` then `sys.argv` is the following list

```py
["test.py", "Elliot"]
```

in which case

```py
"Elliot" in sys.argv
```

would return `True`

By the way, you also don't need the `()` around your if conditions.

Edit: To answer your question in your comment to this answer:

```php
<?php
  $aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
  } 
  else 
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);
    // convert the array of checked values to a space-separated string
    $args = implode(" ", $aDoor)
    // use an interpolated string with the arguments in command string (note the double quotes)
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python3 test.py $args"); 
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");      
    }
    echo $output;
  }
?>
```

Comment: and how do i place checked checkbox's Value like  `python3 test.py Acorn Elliot` if i checked Elliot and Acorn?

Comment: @VinceMacKenzie I edited my answer to answer your comment